# REST products web service filter by Price Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, api, rest-api, filter

Magento **1.9** provides a web service for products but the response parameters that are different for customer/guest and admin.

The problem is that there is a price field in Admin response that gives the exact price of the product while there is no direct price field response in Customer/guest due to which the price filter on the guest response is not working. The fields provided for customer/guest is *`regular_price_with_tax, regular_price_without_tax, final_price_with_tax` and `final_price_without_tax`* and filter cannot be applied on basis of these.

**www.magentohost.com/api/rest/products?order=regular_price_with_tax&dir=dsc**

does not change the output and

**www.magentohost.com/api/rest/products?order=price&dir=dsc**

throws an error. Filter for name is working fine and gives required output.

Is there any way by which the price filter can work for guest and customer?